# How to use hover to menu

Tags: css

my css is:

```
.jokesmenu  li a:hover {
    background-color: #35afe3;
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(
        linear, 
        left top, 
        left bottom, 
        from(rgb(69, 199, 235)),
        to(rgb(38, 152, 219))
    );
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(
        top, 
        rgb(69, 199, 235), 
        rgb(38, 152, 219)
    );
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        rgb(69, 199, 235), 
        rgb(38, 152, 219)
    );
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(
        top, 
        rgb(69, 199, 235), 
        rgb(38, 152, 219)
    );
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(
        top, 
        rgb(69, 199, 235), 
        rgb(38, 152, 219)
    );
background-image:linear-gradient(
        top, 
        rgb(69, 199, 235), 
        rgb(38, 152, 219)
    );
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(
        GradientType=0,
        StartColorStr='#45c7eb', 
        EndColorStr='#2698db'
    );
color:#fff;
    list-style:none;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

and the html is:

```
<ul class="jokesmenu">
            <li class="jokesmenu"><a href="http://www.domain.com/jokes_sms/">SMS<span><?php echo $jokes_sms; ?></span></a>    </li>

</ul>
```

How do I hover the menu by using the above css? I used the jokesmenu as li.

Comment: What do you mean by "how to hover the mennu"?

Comment: everything in your code works to activate a hover state on the `a` tag.. if you are wanting to activate hover on the entire `li` change your css to this `.jokesmenu  li:hover`

Comment: Tab hovers , i want to hover to current tab

Comment: Seems odd to have the same class name for your <ul> and <li>.. I feel like this might cause some conflicts in the future.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do? If you hover the link within the list you want that lists background to change?

if so try removing the "jokesmenu" class from the li and set up two CSS rules

```
ul.jokesmenu { background: #eee; }
ul.jokesmenu li a:hover > ul.jokesmenu { background: #000; }

<ul class="jokesmenu">
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

So this should change the lists background when you hover the link. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make li as active or hover stage.
Then you have to jquery

```
$("li a").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).parent('li').removeClass('active');
  }
);
```